# How can I update my AJAX settings from within an AJAX call?

Tags: jquery

I am writing a chat application and want to get settings for all subsequent AJAX calls in the first chat call.

I set the default jQuery AJAX settings:

```
jQ.ajaxSetup({
  url : 'chat.php',
  contentType: 'application/json'
  dataType : 'json',
  type : 'post'
});
```

Then I pass the action to return a JSON object containing the data to connect to the specific chat.

```
jQ.ajax({
  data: {
    'action' : 'connect'
  },
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
    // set user ID and chat ID for all subsequent ajax calls
      if (data.partner) {
      // start fetching data to listen for messages
      } else {
      // keep checking for partner
      }
    } else {
    //  chat connect failed
    }
  }
});
```

If the chat is created and the user is connected to a chat partner, Every 0.2 seconds I fetch data from the server like so:

```
setTimeout(fetchData, 200);
function fetchData(){
  jQ.ajax({
    data: {
      'action' : 'fetch'
    },
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        // update messages
      }
      setTimeout(fetchData, 200);
  });
}
```

I also have AJAX functions to post data and disconnect from the chat, and basically they will all need to have the same chat credentials as set by the initial 'connect' action.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Create a data object in the shared scope that you can pass with subsequent requests to fetch data that contains the client id information

Comment: I did think about doing that but was wondering if there was any other way to do it as it would require extending the object with the 'action' property!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i would do. store the credentials in a "global" object and then extend that global object with an action as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object that contains the credentials in a global scope, then extend it with the action as needed.

```
var credentials = {};
```

update that object with the first ajax request, then subsequent ones would simply add to the object:

```
credentials.action = "fetch";

...
data: credentials,
...
```

Unless you are adding more than action, you don't really need to extend it. Otherwise, extend it with:

```
data: $.extend({},credentials,{ action: "fetch", foo: "bar" }),
```

Comment: I forgot about dot syntax, which is strange because I use it to extend the `this` object!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you're feeding a JSON object to the `ajax` function.

You can store the settings in a variable, like so:

```
var ajax_settings = {
    data: { ... },
    success: function(data) { ... },
};
```

And use that in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax(ajax_settings);
```

Change the `ajax_settings` variable after you connect or otherwise as needed.

Comment: Kevin B said something similar in a comment which made more sense (since I need a different success function for each call), creating an object to pass to the data object which would have to be extended with the 'action' property. His approach would be correct although the theory behind the idea is the same.